# Creating logic with jQuery depending on where the user hovers their mouse

Tags: jquery

I have a list item that when a user hover theirs mouse over it, a div on the page animates.  The problem I'm having is what happens next.  When the user moves their mouse off the original list item, if they move it over the div that originally animated, I have the logic working from there no problem.  The problem is what happens if the user hovers off the list item and does not hover over the animated div.  I'm trying to create a function that accounts for this later situation.  If the user hovers off the list item (li.solutions) and they do *NOT* hover over the animated div that just showed up, the animated div hides again.

I've posted the basic code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9bE2p/

Comment: That fiddle doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't seem to work for me. I also have a hard time understanding your story.

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that you want the `div` shown when `li` is hovered, and when the user hovers away from both the `div` and the `li`, the `div` must be hidden.

If so, than this might be what you are looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // hide nav_top_dropdown first
    $('.nav_top_dropdown').hide();

    // set hover functionality, also on the hidden dropdown
    $('.solutions, .nav_top_dropdown').hover(function(){
        $('.nav_top_dropdown').show();       
    }, function(){
        // hovering off situation
        $('.nav_top_dropdown').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: thnx for your response!  the problem is once I hover off the nav item onto the dropdown, the dropdown slides back up.  you're response is the direction i'm trying to go.  just have to figure out how to cancel the dropdown from sliding back up if i hover over the dropdown after leaving the list item.

Comment: Is it possible for you to change your HTML? Because in this situation, it might be better to use proper nesting (put the div-element in the li-element, so that the li-hover event expands over the div)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is the sort of thing you want. Basically it starts the hide action when you leave the menu, but delays it to provide a chance to cancel, if e.g. the user moves the cursor onto the dropdown. If they do, the hide is reinstated when they move off the dropdown.

```
var timerId;
function maybeHideDropdown() {
    function hideDropdown() {
       $(this).removeClass('nav_down').animate({'top': '-120px'}, 1000);
    }
    timerId = setTimeout(hideDropdown, 200);
}

function cancelHideDropdown() {
  clearTimeout(timerId);
}

$('.solutions').hover(
  function () { 
    cancelHideDropdown(); // in case they move from dropdown back to menu
    $('.nav_top_dropdown').animate({'top': '+60px'}, 1000).addClass('nav_down');
  },
  function () {
    maybeHideDropdown();
  }
);

$('.nav_top_dropdown').hover (
  function () {
    cancelHideDropdown();
    $(this).addClass('nav_down');
  },
  function () {
    maybeHideDropdown();
  }
);
```